# difference between product of positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices

Let X,Y,U is positive definite matrices such that Y-U is positive definite. Is Y*XY-U*XU positive definite? what about if we take those matrices as nonnegative positive matrices.

Comment: Not sure if this is true. However, it may help to note that
$$
YXY - UXU = (Y - U)X(Y - U) + (YXU + UXY)
$$
The key (I think) is to figure out whether $(YXU + UXY)$ is necessarily positive (semi)definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A randomly generated example disproves the hypothesis. All matrices
$$
X=U=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&1},
\quad
Y=\pmatrix{3&2\\2&3},
\quad Y-U=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&2}.
$$
are positive definite, but
$$
YXY-UXU=\pmatrix{21&23\\23&24}
$$
is not. Since all matrices are positive (and hence nonnegative), this also disproves the second hypothesis.

Comment: pavel, how do you randomly generate positive definite matrices?

Comment: @abel For this example, I simply took a random integer matrix $A$ with positive entries (generated by `randi` in MATLAB) and took $A^TA$. It's of course not necessary for $A$ to have positive entries, it was just to guarantee that $A^TA$ is positive. You can also generate a random positive definite diagonal matrix `D=diag(rand(n,1))` and transform it with a random orthogonal matrix `Q=orth(rand(n))`.

Comment: pavel, thanks. i think i need to learn how to use matlab.

Comment: @abel You're welcome! It's not so complicated :-)